# How to get snappy enable-classic?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Great talk by Sergio Schvezov at Ubucon Pasadena today - he demod a temporary way around the read-only file system (apparently a form of containerising)

$ snappy enable-classic

I'm just running in the demo kvm image for now and if I try that I just get ~"command not recognised"

Nothing comes up if you do snappy search enable-classic and google doesn't provide anything else

How do I get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be running all-snaps 16.04 Ubuntu Core, images found here: http://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/ .

Then that command will work :) . Soon that will become the 16.04 version of Ubuntu Core.

Comment: The answer of @popey below is the more recent answer to this. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This command has now changed in recent versions of snappy to the following:-

```
sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge
```

Followed by the following to enter classic mode:-

```
sudo classic
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu core 18:

```
sudo snap install --channel=18/edge classic --devmode
```

In my case, it complained about my user not existing so I did:

```
sudo SUDO_USER=root classic
```