# Availability of classic snap for Ubuntu Core 18

Tags: ubuntu-core

I just installed the classic snap on a dragonboard 410c running UC18 using:

`snap install classic --edge --devmode`

After install I was informed that the classic version is 16.04, and that other channels have the version for uc18. I cannot find the version for uc18.

Is it available, and if so how do I install it?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary, but the thread linked below has answers to this question, precisely.

[How to get snappy enable-classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724026/how-to-get-snappy-enable-classic)

However, unless you are interested in doing a lot of package building, I would consider using classic core16 until classic core18 is fully vetted on the system.  Core16 will run just fine in classic mode.  If you're not yet at the point where you're trying to go Beta with a release image, might be easier to just do it this way.

**Update:**
I just tried on a dragonboard, and it seems like core18 classic snap is no longer available for dragonboard.  Quite a shame.

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this issue, and tried to find a way to build the `classic` Snap for `armhf` with Ubuntu Core 18. I ended up forking the [classic-snap](https://github.com/snapcore/classic-snap) repo, into [classic-snap-armhf](https://github.com/seanlano/classic-snap-armhf). I didn't push this to the Snap Store though, I haven't tested it anywhere near enough for it to seem like that is a good idea.

Assuming you've already got `snapcraft` and the new `multipass` build tools installed, you should be able to build the Snap yourself, like so:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/seanlano/classic-snap-armhf.git
$ cd classic-snap-armhf
$ snapcraft clean
$ snapcraft --target-arch=armhf
```

This should produce `classic-armhf_core18-1_armhf.snap`, copy this to your device with SCP (or any other way), then install it and give it the right permissions with:

```
$ sudo snap install --dangerous --devmode classic-armhf_core18-1_armhf.snap
$ sudo snap connect classic-armhf:classic-support :classic-support
```

Then you can use the classic environment with:

```
$ sudo classic-armhf
```

Comment: I've also made the Snap package available as a GitHub release: https://github.com/seanlano/classic-snap-armhf/releases/tag/core18-1

This still needs to be installed as above.